# Squid: Occasional Blank Pages

Tags: squid

I am using squid for an internal proxy for our network.  On occasion, I have had issues where squid throws back a blank page 2-3 times before finally loading.  One especially apparent time for this is when logging into facebook.  The relevant parts of the squid configuration are below (everything else is all ACL related).

```
maximum_object_size 100240 KB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 5 MB

# Trying to fix blank pages...
forward_timeout 1 minutes
connect_timeout 30 seconds
negative_ttl 0 minutes    
positive_dns_ttl 10 seconds
negative_dns_ttl 10 seconds
dns_nameservers 4.2.2.1 4.2.2.2
forwarded_for off
```

Any ideas as to what I could change around to avoid hitting blank pages would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it internally shouldnt you be using internal DNS servers not external DNS 4.2.2.1 4.2.2.2?
Or have I misunderstood your question?
The reason I say this is that I had a similar problem with DNS that produced a similar output.

Comment: The root DNS servers are in there because I was trying to determine if it was a nameserver issue.  I've switched them back to use the internal DNS servers, thanks for pointing that out (I forgot I had that in there).  It does not solve the problem though.